# Javascript module pattern - losing scope of this

Tags: javascript, scope

Been working on a js module pattern for a while to meet the escalating needs of "some website". Essentially, I just need a good way of grouping / encapsulating scripts, along with the sometime need for OO patterns.

I've got a structure that works ok, but I'm not happy with certain parts of it... so I'm in the process of refactoring it. Here is the updated pattern:

```
(function (global) {
    var M = {
        VERSION : 1.0
    };

    global.M = M;

    //jQ document.ready()
    global.onload = function(){
        console.log('M VERSION: %s', M.VERSION);
        var main = new M.Main();
    };

    M.Main = function(){
        var _class1;
        var _class2;
        var _class3;

        function _init(){
            _class1 = new M.Class('foo','baz');
            console.log('_class1.param2 : %s', _class1.getParam() ); //works

            _class2 = new M.OtherClass('faz','boo');
            _class2.setParam('Boozaz');
            console.log('_class2.param2 : %s', _class2.getParam() ); //works

            _class3 = new M.Class('fuz','boz')
            console.log('_class3.param2 : %s', _class3.getParam() ); //works

            _class3.prototype = new M.Super();
            console.log('_class3.__param : %s', _class3.prototype.getProtected() ) //works
        }

        _init();
        return true;
    };

    M.Super = function(){
        var __param = 'jQ';
        M.Super.API = {
            getProtected : function(){ return __param }
        }
        return M.Super.API;
    }

    M.Class = function( p1, p2){
        var _param1;
        var _param2;

        function _init(){
            _param1 = p1;
            _param2 = p2;
        }

        function _getParam(){
            return _param2;
        }

        function _setParam(e){
            _param2 = e;
        }

        M.Class.API = {
            getParam : function(){ return _getParam(); },
            setParam : function(e){ _setParam(e) },
            publicMethod : function(){  ...  }
        }

        publicMethod() //fails
        this.publicMethod() //fails, this scopes to DOM window
        M.Class.API.publicMethod() // works, but is kludgy

        _init();
        return M.Class.API;
    };

})(typeof window === 'undefined' ? this : window);
```

This produces a satisfactory DOM structure (on inspection via firebug) - but I'm losing scope of `this` in one specific area = calling the "public" methods of the returned object, internally.

```
publicMethod() //fails
this.publicMethod() //fails, this scopes to DOM window
M.Class.API.publicMethod() // works, but kludgy syntax
```

In the previous iteration of this pattern, the "class" object is self-executing, and reference to `this` is maintained :

```
    M.Class = function( p1, p2){
        var _param1;
        var _param2;
        var _root; 

        function _init(){
            _root   = this; //this gets referenced for later usage
            _param1 = p1;
            _param2 = p2;
        }

        function _getParam(){
            return _param2;
        }

        function _setParam(e){
            _param2 = e;
        }

        M.Class.API = {
            init     : function(){ _init();    },
            getParam : function(){ return _getParam(); },
            setParam : function(e){ _setParam(e) },
        }

        console.log('getParam, internal :%s', _root.getParam() ) //success
        return M.Class.API;
    }();

  M.Class.init();
```

However, in the refactored pattern, I wish instantiate these "classes" via `new`, to gain more control over execution order.

I've read many, many articles on the fairly mind numbing subject of lexical scope in js... yet come up with no conclusions.

**How should I maintain the scope of `this` in my updated module pattern?**

Comment: Say 1,000 times: **this is not scope, it's a special local variable set by the call** (or ES5 *bind*).

Comment: Not sure how `this` is scoping to `window` and not `M.Class`. An obvious solution, however maybe not feasible for you, would be to declare a wrapper function in M.Class to call M.Class.API's equivalent function for you. If you're attempting to set what `this` refers to within `publicFunction` look into `call()` and `apply()`.

Comment: How do you use `M.Class` inside of `M.Class`? It should be undefined, isn't it?

Comment: @Nemoden no it should be defined within it. Functions can reference themselves. http://jsfiddle.net/DgBaa/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those philosophical questions that everyone asks when writing a library or module: should functions reference the container object using *this* or the variable name? The answer is: it depends.

If you know that the function will always be called with the correct value of *this* (e.g. a method on a prototype), then use *this*. However, if the function might be called any other way, then use the variable name. If you decide at some later stage to change the name, it's a pretty simple search and replace exercise. And calling *myLib.utils.someFn* is a lot clearer than calling *this.someFn* to me. And if you feel it's too much typing, you can always revert to `var sF = myLib.utils.someFn` and go from there.

#### Edit

To answer your questions:

```
publicMethod() //fails
```

There is no `publicMethod` identifier in the current scope, it will fail.

```
     this.publicMethod() //fails, this scopes to DOM window
```

If the call was M.Class(), then *this* is a reference to *M*. If you are getting *window*, then you are calling the function some other way.

```
     M.Class.API.publicMethod() // works, but is kludgy
```

Because that is how you have set it up. If you don't like it, set it up some other way.

Lastly:

```
)(typeof window === 'undefined' ? this : window);
```

seems to be one of those mystic incantations that seem to proliferate on the web. What is the purpose? If the intent is to pass a reference to the global object to the function, then:

```
)(this);
```

is sufficient everywhere. The purpose of the above is to ensure that the function has a reference to the global object because referencing *window* might resolve to some other object. Including logic that may or may not pass in the global object seems like a backward step. In what scenario is it preferable to reference the (possibly re-assigned) *window* property of the global object rather than the global object itself?

Comment: There is a difference if there are multiple "instances" of the `function`. Using the name directly is similar (however not exactly the same) as declaring a static member in OO languages on a class.

Comment: Naturally if there are multiple instances, object properties should be set up so *this* references the instance. However, it all goes back to how functions are called—you can only guarantee the value of *this* where you are in control of the call.

Comment: @RobG - thanks for the reply. Funny and frustrating how much _philosophy_ comes into play when structuring js. Many valid ways to do a single thing... At any rate I totally get what you're saying. I think what probably makes sense is to use both patterns when applicable. Some "classes" in this architecture, after all, only need a single instance. As for your individual points - I was just very surprised that 'this' resolved to 'Window' in the second situation (posted code being only slightly modified from my live code) perhaps I  have some wires crossed...

Comment: @RobG ... Also - whats not to love about _mystical incantations_ in your code. Everyone who looks at it (your boss, especially) will say to themselves "wow. you are, indeed, a smart fellah". Lol. You're point is well taken. I think I scraped it up from some post long ago, and just seemed to be a good failsafe when setting up an initial object. But you're right - what the hell else would 'this' refer to in that situation? Cheers...

Comment: Ha! Yes, people love those things, they're so damn sexy. Until someone asks "why". :-)

Answer (score 1):

What if all of your methods were "private" except the ones you manually expose through `M.Class.API`?

```
function _getParam(){
  return _param2;
}

function _setParam(e){
  _param2 = e;
}

function publicMethod(){
  console.log("public method");
}

M.Class.API = {
  getParam : _getParam,
  setParam : _setParam,
  publicMethod : publicMethod
}

publicMethod();              // succeeds
this.publicMethod();         // still fails
M.Class.API.publicMethod();  // still works, still is kludgy
```

You should also be aware that returning an anonymous object from a function may have unintended consequences when calling that function with the `new` keyword. See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304473/creating-objects-from-js-closure-should-i-use-the-new-keyword).

Comment: Interesting point on your attached link. I seldom do custom type checking in JS just for this reason (rather - a more cumbersome prop check like 'is obj typeof 'object' && obj.hasOwnProperty('someProp') && obj['someProp'] != 'undefined' '. At any rate - "public" methods that just invoke "private" methods can certainly work, and may be included in my final refactor... Cheers!