# What's the difference between `f()` and `new f()`?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)
>   [creating objects from JS closure: should i use the “new” keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304473/creating-objects-from-js-closure-should-i-use-the-new-keyword)

See this code:

```
function friend(name) {
    return { name: name };
}

var f1 = friend('aa');
var f2 = new friend('aa');

alert(f1.name); // -> 'aa'
alert(f2.name); // -> 'aa'
```

What's the difference between `f1` and `f2`?
​

Comment: One has the word "new" in front of it :-)   One is just a regular function, and the other is a new instance of something, usually an object, and just about everything is an object in JS.

Comment: I think this is very much eloquent question in compare to the other duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new in your case isn't usefull.
You only need to use the new keyword when the function uses the 'this' keyword.

```
function f(){
    this.a;
}
// new is required.
var x = new f();

function f(){
    return {
        a:1
    }
}
// new is not required.
var y = f();
```

Comment: bit neared to answer but still need a thorough explanation i guess.