# closure can use new keyword and what is difference for instance, when creating a new object/class

Tags: javascript

I am new and going on javascript way. At the point of **Closure**. I can create object with `new` keyword and without `new` keyword, it is so **weird** me.

Here code:-

```
          function RankingManage(rank) {
                var rank = rank;
                function rankInc() {
                    rank++;
                }
                function rankDec() {
                    rank--;
                }

                return {
                    makeInc: function () {
                        rankInc();
                    },
                    makeDec: function () {
                        rankDec();
                    },
                    showRank: function () {
                        return rank;
                    }
                }
            }

            var Rank = new RankingManage(80);
            var Rank2 = RankingManage(80);
            Rank.makeInc();
            Rank2.makeInc();
            console.log(Rank.showRank());//Output:- 81
            console.log(Rank2.showRank());//Output:- 81
```

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript/3658673#3658673

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating objects from JS closure: should i use the "new" keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304473/creating-objects-from-js-closure-should-i-use-the-new-keyword)

Comment: The closure here is letting you define variables and functions without them entering the global namespace. The `new` here does nothing useful as as `RankingManage` is returning an _Object_

Comment: when you use return in closure with obj syntax `{}` it already creates a new object for you, no point of using `new` again. makes sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're creating and returning an object (with the `return { ... }`), you wouldn't normally call `RankingManage` via `new`. You're not using the object that the `new` operator creates, and you're overriding the default result of the `new` expression by returning a non-`null` object from the function. So both ways work, but it doesn't make sense to use `new` with your function as currently written.

Your current function is absolutely fine, just call it wihtout `new`. (And since it's not a constructor function — a function you call with `new` — you'd start it with a lower-case letter, by convention, not an upper-case one. So `rankingManage`.)

**If** you wanted to require `new` when calling `RankingManage`, you could use the object that `new` creates via the `this` keyword:

```
function RankingManage(rank) {
    var rank = rank;

    function rankInc() {
        rank++;
    }

    function rankDec() {
        rank--;
    }

    this.makeInc = rankInc;
    this.makeDec = rankDec;
    this.showRank = function() {
        return rank;
    };
}
```

We don't use a `return` in that, because (again) the default result of the `new RankingManage` expression is a reference to the object that `new` created.

But again, your existing function is fine.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with closures.

Using `new` sets the value of `this` for the function to a new object and causes it to return `this` by default.

You are using a `return` statement to explicitly return an object, so you return that object instead of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, things are done a little bit differently when you're defining an object in this way.

```
public function MyObject(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.doSomething = function() { console.log("Hello!"); };
}

var myObject = new MyObject(10);
var notObject = MyObject(10);

myObject.doSomething(); // Prints Hello!
notObject.doSomething(); // Prints out "can not get property of undefined"
```

You will now see a change in behaviour, because `new` prevents the default behaviour of adding values to `window` and adds them to an object that gets returned.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLx3376n/

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we've the following function:

```
function Car(color){
    this.wheels = 4;
    this.color = color;
}
```

What exactly `new` operator does (`new Car('red');`) could be stated as follows:

- Create an empty object and make the `this` inside the function to point to.
- Invoke the function. (Note that `this` points to that empty object).
- That empty object will be populated with properties: `wheels` and `color`.
- Implicitly returns that object. (If you have explicit `return` statement, that object of `this` will be discarded.)

At the end, your returned object is of this structure:

```
{
    wheels: 4,
    color: 'red'
}
```